# How to extract the name of a dataframe from a list and print it as a heading to the output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

[image]My `list1` contains 4 dataframes such as:

`group_high`, `group_medium`, `group_low`, `group_rba`.

I have created a for loop so that each dataframe goes inside the loop and provides an output.

Before the output is printed i wanted my code to have the dataframe name as the heading so that i will be able to identify to which dataframe the results belongs to.

Example: Before `group_high` dataframe results are printed, I want to have a heading as `group_high` which is then followed by the output of `group_high`. Similarly i need it for all other dataframes in `list1`.

Below is my code:

```
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\91979\Downloads\head code\src')
from classStruct.model import model
list1 = [group_high,group_medium,group_low,group_rba]
for i in list1:
    needed_cols = i.columns
    target_col =  ['Rejection (%)']
    cols = list(set(needed_cols) - set(target_col))
    totData = i
    totData = totData.round(decimals=2)
    Model1 = model(totData,cols,['Rejection (%)'])
    clustSet = pd.DataFrame([C.clusterCenter for C in Model1.clustersList])
    Model1.predictor(clustSet, ["Rejection (%)"], Normalize=False)
    Model1.optimalClusterRejectionSeries = round(min(clustSet['Rejection (%)Predicted']),4)
    col_list = ['GCS (kg/cm2)', 'Inert Fines (%)', 'Volatile Matter (%)',
       'LOI (%)', 'Active Clay (%)', 'GFN/AFS (no)', 'Compactability (%)',
       'Wet Tensile Strength (gm/cm2)', 'Moisture (%)',
       'Permeability (no)', 'Temp. of Sand after mix.(C)']
    Model1.deNormalizeColumns(col_list, clustSet).to_csv("Predicted_optimal.csv")
    Model1.deNormalizeColumns(col_list, clustSet)
    print(pd.DataFrame(clustSet[clustSet['Rejection (%)Predicted'] == clustSet['Rejection (%)Predicted'].min()]))
    print('\n')
    print('\n')
```

Comment: dataframes do not store `self.name`... you need to provide it yourself with something like `for i, name in zip(list1, names_list):`

Comment: @RichieV if i have a separate list2 which contains all the heading which i wanted before an output is printed . In which part of my code should i insert it? `list2 = ["Group High", "Group Medium", "Group Low", Group RBA"`

Comment: I guess i need to do something like `for j in list2: print j` but which part of the code should i do it.

Comment: did you see my answer? `names_list` in my code is your `list2`... get used to using dicts for this case, and even a full df when possible

Comment: @RichieV i get the output but the code gives 16 results whereas i need only 4. Only the first 4 outputs. From the 5th till 16th it is the duplicate of the first 4 outputs. How can i remove them?  `list1 = [group_high,group_medium,group_low,group_rba]
names_list = ["Group High:", "Group Medium:", "Group Low:", "Group RBA:"]
for i, name in zip(list1, names_list):
    all_dfs = {name: df for name, df in zip(names_list, list1)}
    for name, df in all_dfs.items():
        print(name)`    if this code is printed it gives 16 names but i need only 4. Can you please help me

Comment: @RichieV please refer to the attached image of what i am trying to convey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dataframes do not store `self.name`... you need to provide it yourself with something like

```
for i, name in zip(list1, names_list):
```

You can decide to gather all dfs in a dictionary

```
all_dfs = {name: df for name, df in zip(names_list, list1)}
# then iterate
for name, df in all_dfs.items():
```

Often if several dfs have the same columns and the index has the same levels it is a good idea to keep them as a single df and use `df.groubpy` to iterate over grouped rows (since your dfs seem to have come from a groupby anyway you could skip the step where you presumably separate into several dfs and iterate straight from the groubpy, if that is your case).

```
# if dfs come from different sources
# concatenate them into a single df
df_main = pd.concat(
    list1, # collection of dfs to be concatenated
    keys=names_list, # names for dfs, will be appended as the outermost index level
    names=['name_of_df'] # name for the level that will be appended
)

# iterate over a groupby object
for name_of_df, df_sub in df_main.groubpy('name_of_df'):
    # name_of_df: string provided in `names_list`
    # df_sub: filtered df
```

---

EDIT:

Please understand that all the code blocks above are exclusive, i.e. pick one solution and stick with it. Your comment is trying to combine the different solutions and on top of that using `all_dfs.items()` which is not in any option provided and is not necessary for this case.

If you choose the first option then

```
for i, name in zip(list1, names_list):
    print(name)
    needed_cols = i.columns # from your code
    # the rest of your code inside the loop
```